# Text input stays above everything in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

It's been a long time since IE9 was a requirement and I'm a bit rusty, so I could use a second set of eyes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles-b.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="v2-header">
        <div id="v2-header-info">
            <div class="v2-frame">
                <a href="" class="v2-logo">Home</a>
                <p class="v2-phone">Call to talk to one of our <em>Parts Specialists</em> <strong id="v2-phone-number">1<span>-</span>805<span>-</span>702<span>-</span>8365</strong></p>
                <ul class="v2-header-links">
                    <li class="v2-header-links-1"><a href="">Help &amp; Support</a>
                        <ul class="v2-header-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="" class="v2-button">Support Online &mdash; Chat Now</a></li>
                            <li><strong>Help &amp; Support</strong></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/american-customer-support/" class="test2">USA Customer Care </a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/order-support.html" class="test3">Order Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/product-support.html">Product Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/warranty.htm">Warranty Info</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/policies.htm" class="test4">Policies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/about.htm">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li class="v2-header-links-2"><a href="">Community</a>
                        <ul class="v2-header-dropdown">
                            <li><strong>Check Us Out</strong></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/web/index.aspx"><span>Blog</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/facebook/"><span>Facebook</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/linkedin/"><span>LinkedIn</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/twitter/"><span>Twitter</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/youtube/"><span>Youtube</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/googleplus/"><span>Google +</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.buyautoparts.com/pinterest/"><span>Pinterest</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="v2-single" href="">How To</a></li>
                    <!--<li><a href="">Buyer's Guides</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="v2-header-action">
            <div class="v2-frame">
                <form action="" id="v2-search">
                    <p class="v2-search-cta">Try our new Parts Search</p>
                    <p class="v2-search-input">
                        <input type="text" name="" value="Try out our new search!" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" />
                    </p>
                    <p class="v2-search-button">
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
                    </p>
                </form>
                <ul id="v2-header-account">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Hello. Sign In. <strong>Your Account</strong></a>
                        <ul class="v2-header-dropdown">
                            <li><a href="" class="v2-button">Sign In</a></li>
                            <li><strong>Your Account</strong></li>
                            <li><a href="">Your Account Information</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Your Orders</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Track Packages</a></li>
                            <li><strong>Process Returns</strong></li>
                            <li><a href="">Return an Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Return a Core</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="v2-header-cart">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Your cart is <strong>Empty</strong></a>
                        <ul class="v2-header-dropdown">
                            <li>
                                <span class="v2-cart-qty">1</span>
                                <a href="" class="v2-cart-title">2002 Chevrolet Cavalier A/C Accumulator/Drier <span>2.2L and 8th VIN digit 4</span></a>
                                <span class="v2-cart-price">$39.00</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="v2-vehicle-selector">
        <form action="">
            <p class="v2-selector-label">Select Your Vehicle</p>
            <p class="v2-selector-dropdown"><select name="" id="">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Year</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select></p>
            <p class="v2-selector-dropdown"><select disabled="disabled" name="" id="">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Make</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select></p>
            <p class="v2-selector-dropdown"><select disabled="disabled" name="" id="">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select Model</option>
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select></p>
            <p class="v2-selector-submit"><input type="submit" value="Go &rsaquo;" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/tozawuko/1/

Hover over Help & Support in IE9 and you'll see that the dropdown sits underneath the search box. Interestingly, the input is not absolutely positioned, but its parent is.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? (Mac user)

Comment: Yeah, no problem. Mac user as well (thank god for parallels). http://i.imgur.com/Rp5QBBT.png

Comment: Change the z-index :)... Will put together something... Big code though

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add the `z-index` on the search box:

```
<input type="text" name="" value="Try out our new search!" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" style="z-index:-1" />
```

Add the `z-index` on the hover dropdown:

```
#v2-header .v2-header-dropdown .v2-button:hover {
    background-color: #faa100;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 100%, 50% 0%, color-stop(0%, #f7891a), color-stop(100%, #ffae0d));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #f7891a 0%, #ffae0d 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #f7891a 0%, #ffae0d 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #f7891a 0%, #ffae0d 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #f7891a 0%, #ffae0d 100%);
    z-index: 9999;
}
/* line 91, ../sass/styles-b.scss */
 #v2-header .v2-header-dropdown li {
    padding: 1px 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Double checked in IE9 and your initial code looks fine to me